# Generic Input to a function

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to get a generic input to my function.

I tried

```
    interface IReport <T , T1>
    {
        List<T> GenerateReport<T1>();
    }
```

But i get warnings on the first T1 , `that it was never used` , and on second T1 `that I declaring with the same name as other type parameter` .

Any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Which version of framework? with 3.5 I can compile the code successfully.

Comment: @PraveenVenu As he said, he is getting warnings not errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to define `T1` at the method, because it's already defined at interface level.

This is correct:

```
interface IReport <T , T1>
{
    List<T> GenerateReport(T1 input);
}
```

Or this:

```
interface IReport <T>
{
    List<T> GenerateReport<T1>(T1 input);
}
```

#### See

[Generic Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've declared the type on the class, you don't have to declare it on the function, it should be something like:

```
interface IReport <T , T1>
{
    List<T> GenerateReport(T1 parameter);
}
```